# Convert php array of objects to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

if i have an associative array in php.

Say, in the same view, i have **$params** array:

```
$parameters = array(
   'parameter1'=>'value1',
   'parameter2'=>'value2
);
```

Is there any way or php function or even javascript function to convert the php array to javascript array? in such a way that if we have the converted array, **jsParameters**, you'd be able to access it's fields and values like :

```
console.log(jsParameters.parameter1);
console.log(jsParameters.parameter2);
```

that will output, 'value1' and 'value2'. Is there a way? many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
console.log(<?php echo json_encode($parameters); ?>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
echo json_encode($parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to call `json_encode` on the array, and echo that back to your application.

Check out the docs [here](https://www.php.net/json_encode)